# How to escape program name in journalctl

Tags: linux, journalctl

My system crashed and I am trying to determine what happened by looking at the logs.
I want to filter the logs for the different programs that caused the errors.
For this I tried:

```
my_username@pop-os:~$ journalctl -u pop-os\ kernel
Invalid unit name "pop-os kernel" escaped as "pop-os\x20kernel" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?).
-- No entries --
```

How do I search for `pop-os kernel` properly?

Answer (score 1):

The `-u` option specifies *systemd unit* name, not program name. For example, `-u named` would show all messages from `named.service` regardless of what program name they're tagged with. If you don't know the corresponding unit (or if there isn't one), use the `-t` option instead.

Also, when you see lines like `Dec 28 14:38:06 pop-os kernel:`, then the program name is just `kernel`, not `pop-os kernel` – the field following the date is the *system hostname*, not part of the program name. So the correct search query would be `-t kernel`.

(But if you're trying to use journalctl as a dmesg replacement, better use the `-k` option to get all messages obtained from the kernel buffer.)